# Python: Automated Email Send Not Delivered to Recipients

Tags: python, email, scripting, automation

I have a script that automates sending an email with a csv attachment. However, it doesn't show up in any of the recipient's inboxes; it does, however, show up in my inbox when I add my email to the to list. The code did not produce any errors. Could someone please kindly identify what's wrong?

```
def sendattach(Subject, AttachFile, AFileName):

    # email contents below
    gmail_user = '123@gmail.com'
    to = ",".join(['123@hotmail.com '456@gmail.com'])
    gmail_pwd = '123456'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = Subject
    msg['From'] = gmail_user
    msg['To'] = to

    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open(AttachFile, "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)

    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=AFileName)

    msg.attach(part)
    msg.attach(MIMEText('Please find attached the weekly refi campaign export', 'plain'))
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()
    s.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    s.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()

def main():
    Run_Report()
    sendattach("Weekly Refi Campaign Export", "FinalRefiCampaign %s" % (str(dt.now().date())) + ".csv",
               "FinalRefiCampaign %s" % (str(dt.now().date())) + ".csv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try using parameter fail_silently=False so that exceptions will be thrown if the sending fails from the machine itself.

Comment: Ok - will do thanks.